# How to deploy with Bitbucket?

Tags: git, deployment, ftp, mercurial, bitbucket

I've read a tutorial that explains how to deploy to server with ftp using Bitbucket Pipelines with git ftp:

https://www.savjee.be/2016/06/Deploying-website-to-ftp-or-amazon-s3-with-BitBucket-Pipelines/

Since I'm using mercurial, git ftp won't work on my repo, and I wish to find a replacement for git ftp that is just as good as it. I.e. uploads only changed files on push etc etc.

.yml:

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://YOUR_SERVER_ADDRESS/PATH_TO_WEBSITE/
```

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial has a FTP extension : [FTPExtension - Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FTPExtension)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, deploy web folder

```
image: php:7.1.24

pipelines:
  branches:
   master:
     - step:
         name: Deploy to production
         deployment: production
         script:
           - apt-get update
           - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
           - git ftp init --user $FTP_USERNAME_PROD --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD_PROD ftp://ftp.YOURDOMAIN.com/___new-test --syncroot web
   develop:
     - step:
         name: Deploy to staging
         deployment: staging
         script:
           - apt-get update
           - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
           - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME_STAGE --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD_STAGE ftp://ftp.YOURDOMAIN.com/ --syncroot web
```